# Synergy server not receiving connections

Tags: windows, synergy

I'm using synergy with two Windows computers (both Win7 64-bit). The server's debug messages state that it doesn't receive any connections. The client connects to the server (right IP and port) and seemingly everything is fine from the client's side.

The config file of the server:

```
section: screens
    huldra:
    switchCorners = none
        switchCornerSize = 0
    Stahlu:
        switchCorners = none
        switchCornerSize = 0
end
section: links
    huldra:
        left = Stahlu
    Stahlu:
        right = huldra
end
section: aliases
    Stahlu:
        main
end
section: options
    heartbeat = 2000
    screenSaverSync = false
    switchDelay = 250
end
```